# Should I use a comma after "personally"?

Tags: punctuation, commas

Should I use a comma after "personally"?

> Personally, I think a bit of cheese and meat isn't bad for us.

Comment: Antonia, that is speech, and you are writing down what is spoken. Don't you pause when you say that? Yes? Then, a comma is warranted.

Comment: The "natural" position for such adverbial elements is immediately before (sometimes *after*) the verb it modifies. So if it's "fronted", as in your example, we ***normally*** set it off with a comma (reflecting at least *slightly* "unusual, non-default" phrasing), even in contexts where a pause in speech might be minimal or non-existent.

Comment: If adverbs of frequency are usually before the verb or between two verbs does this rule apply to other adverbs? If either "I personally think" or "I think personally" is correct, is either position correct in a negative statement. "I personally don't think", "I don't personally think" or "I don't think personally." Or "Personally, I don't think."  I think the middle position is wrong. Should I start a new thread?

Comment: I think you should start a new thread for your new question. It might be a good idea to lnk back here to show context.

Answer (score 1):

Commas are usually used after [sentence adverbs](https://theeditorsblog.net/2016/02/21/a-tale-of-adverbs-and-the-comma/), but this has to do more with norms of style and prescriptivism rather than strict grammaticality.

In general, especially if you're writing something formal: use a comma. If you're casually texting someone: it doesn't matter.